# raiz de un numero

Tags: c

Agradecería si alguien pudiera revisar mi código, solamente necesito saber porque la función me retorna siempre r=0. Lo que mi programa hace es mediante una serie de operaciones calcular la raíz de un numero entero A, habiendo ingresado previamente este numero y una tolerancia admitida.El problema es que siempre a respuesta que me da es 0.00. No encuentro el error. Muchas gracias.
El codigo es:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    float calculo_raiz(float,float);
    int main()
   {
float rta;
float numero;
float tol;
printf("\n\t\t ¿¿¿ AVERIGUA LA RAIZ CUADRADA ???\n\n" );
printf("Usted desea averiguar la raiz del numero:");
scanf("%f",&numero);
printf("\nIngrese la tolerancia que admitira en el resultado:" );
scanf("%f",&tol);
rta=calculo_raiz(numero,tol);
printf("\nLa raiz de %.2f es %.2f\n",numero,rta);

return 0;
   }

  float calculo_raiz(float num,float tolerancia)
   {
float r=0;
float ra=1;
int inc=1;

while(inc>=1)
{
    r=1/2*(ra+(num/ra));

    if((r-ra)<tolerancia)
    {
        return r;
    }
    else
    {
        inc++;
        ra=r;
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: micaela, bienvenid@ a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio.  Para más información, lee [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Me parece que eso no es PHP, parece mas C o C++, deberias aclarar un poco mas.

Comment: @LuisFernando no, no lo es, etiquete incorrectamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Jorgesys muchas gracias!

Comment: que es eso de la tolerancia?

Comment: @micaela dentro del `While` luego de realizar el calculo `r=1/2*(ra+(num/ra));` imprime la variable `r` a ver que valores te esta generando

Comment: @LuisFernando la tolerancia es la diferencia entre dos terminos sucesivos. Una cota prefijada por el usuario.

Comment: @CesarRomero, me imprime el mismo valor que dije en la pregunta: 0.

Answer (score 2):

bueno, aplicando lo de la tolerancia solo tuve que agregar parentesis a la operacion en el codigo que tines, 1/2 lo cambien por 0.5 porque ese resultado hacia que diera 0, ya funciona tu codigo con esas modificaciones @

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
float calculo_raiz(float,float);
int main()
{
float rta;
float numero;
float tol;
printf("\n\t\t ¿¿¿ AVERIGUA LA RAIZ CUADRADA ???\n\n" );
printf("Usted desea averiguar la raiz del numero:");
scanf("%f",&numero);
printf("\nIngrese la tolerancia que admitira en el resultado:" );
scanf("%f",&tol);
rta=calculo_raiz(numero,tol);
printf("\nLa raiz de %.2f es %.2f\n",numero,rta);

return 0;
}

float calculo_raiz(float num,float tolerancia)
{
float r=0;
float ra=1;
int inc=1;

while(inc>=1)
{
r=(0.5*(ra+(num/ra)));

if((r-ra)<tolerancia)
{
    return r;
}
else
{
    inc++;
    ra=r;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Como sugerencia, cuando la pregunta no esta del todo clara (en este caso, pediste que te aclararan lo de la `tolerancia`) deberías esperar a que aclaren tu duda. La tolerancia es una condición que se debe cumplir en este caso `la raíz es aceptada` cuando sea menor que la `tolerancia`.

Comment: muchas gracias!Pero debo usar la tolerancia y la operacion quehice en el while. La tolerancia es la diferencia entre dos terminos sucesivos, el usuario debe ingresar dicha tolerancia. Cuando la diferencia sea menor a la tolerancia prefijada, la funcion devolvera la respuesta.

Comment: @micaela ya edite mi respuesta, lo que hace que siempre sea 0.00 es la multiplicacion por 1/2, imagino que al redondear no toma 0.5 sino que toma 0 y al multiplicar por los otros valores siempre se hace 0 tu respuesta.

Comment: lo tomare en cuenta @CesarRomero gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el 1/2 ya que estas dividiendo enteros y el resultado te lo regresará como entero:

**1** / **2** = **0**<del>.5</del>

Ponlo con decimales para que te regrese un float

1.0/2.0 = 0.5

Comment: muchisimas gracias!!!!! Ese era el problema!Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunas adecuaciones, no comprendo para que ocupas la tolerancia, igual agrego la función para el calcula de la raíz cuadrada.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    float calculo_raiz(float,float);

    int main(){
        float rta;
        float numero;
        float tol;
        float n;
        printf("\n\t\t ¿¿¿ AVERIGUA LA RAIZ CUADRADA ???\n\n" );
        printf("Usted desea averiguar la raiz del numero:");
        scanf("%f",&numero);
        printf("\nIngrese la tolerancia que admitira en el resultado:" );
        scanf("%f",&tol);
        rta=calculo_raiz(numero,tol);
        printf("\nLa raiz de %.2f es %.2f\n",numero,rta);
        n=sqrt(numero);
        printf("\n Con sqrt La raiz de %.2f es %.2f\n",numero,n);
        return 0;
   }

    float calculo_raiz(float num,float tolerancia){
        float ra,aux; 
        int inc;
        ra=num; 
        float r=0;
        inc=1;
        while(inc){
            aux=num/ra;
            if(ra==aux){
                return ra;
                inc=0;
            }else{
                ra=(0.5)*((num/ra)+ra); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: gracias!Pero debo usar la tolerancia y la operacion que hice en el while. La tolerancia es la diferencia entre dos terminos sucesivos, el usuario debe ingresar dicha tolerancia. Cuando la diferencia sea menor a la tolerancia prefijada, la funcion devolvera la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que en la parte del cálculo en la que utilizas `(1/2)`.

```
28: r=(1/2)*(ra+(num/ra));
```

Al realizar esta operación aritmética, el compilador interpreta la operación como una división entre enteros, dando como resultado 0<strike>.5</strike>. Por lo tanto, al arrojar `0` como resultado de esa operación y multiplicarla por el resto de la expresión, el valor de `r` se convierte a `0`.

En esta pregunta de Stack Overflow en inglés podrás ver una mejor explicación del tema:

> [Why is (1/2)*x different from 0.5*x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764677/why-is-1-2x-different-from-0-5x)

Para que el compilador lo tome como un número flotante, o con parte decimal, tienes que cambiar los valores por:

> `(1/2)` **por** `(1.0/2.0)`
>
> **ó**
>
> `(1/2)` **por** `0.5`

Este tema se explica en el siguiente capítulo del curso:

[9. Conversión de tipos.](http://c.conclase.net/curso/index.php?cap=009#inicio)

> En estos casos, cuando los operandos de cada operación binaria
>   asociados a un operador son de distinto tipo, el compilador los
>   convierte a un tipo común. Existen reglas que rigen estas
>   conversiones, y aunque pueden cambiar ligeramente de un compilador a
>   otro, en general serán más o menos así:
>
> 1. Cualquier tipo entero pequeño como **char** o **short** es convertido a **int** o **unsigned int**. En este punto cualquier pareja de operandos será **int** (con o sin signo), **long**, **long long**, **double**, **float** o **long double**.
> 2. Si un operando es de tipo **long double**, el otro se convertirá a **long double**.
> 3. Si un operando es de tipo **double**, el otro se convertirá a **double**.
> 4. Si un operando es de tipo **float**, el otro se convertirá a **float**.
> 5. Si un operando es de tipo **unsigned long long**, el otro se convertirá a **unsigned long long**.
> 6. Si un operando es de tipo **long long**, el otro se convertirá a **long long**.
> 7. Si un operando es de tipo **unsigned long**, el otro se convertirá a **unsigned long**.
> 8. Si un operando es de tipo **long**, el otro se convertirá a **long**.
> 9. Si un operando es de tipo **unsigned int**, el otro se convertirá a **unsigned int**.
> 10. Llegados a este punto ambos operandos son **int**.

Este caso puede explicarse con un ejemplo de la cita del curso:

[4. Operadores I.](http://c.conclase.net/curso/index.php?cap=004#inicio)

> Veamos, por ejemplo, la expresión 17 / 7, es decir 17 dividido entre
>   7. Cuando aprendimos a dividir, antes de que supiéramos sacar decimales, nos enseñaron que el resultado de esta operación era 2, y
>   el resto 3, es decir 2*7+3 = 17.
>
> En C++, cuando las expresiones que intervienen en una de estas
>   operaciones sean enteras, el resultado también será entero, es decir,
>   si 17 y 7 se almacenan en variables enteras, el resultado será entero,
>   en este caso 2.
>
> Por otro lado si las expresiones son en punto flotante, con decimales,
>   el resultado será en punto flotante, es decir, 2.428571. En este caso:
>   7*2.428571=16.999997, o sea, que no hay resto, o es muy pequeño.
>
> Por eso mismo, calcular el resto, usando el operador %, sólo tiene
>   sentido si las expresiones implicadas son enteras, ya que en caso
>   contrario se calcularán tantos decimales como permita la precisión de
>   tipo utilizado.
>
> Siguiendo con el ejemplo, la expresión 17 % 7 dará como resultado 3,
>   que es el resto de la división entera de 17 dividido entre 7.

Quedando así tu código corregido:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float calculo_raiz(float,float);

int main()
{
    float rta;
    float numero;
    float tol;
    printf("\n\t\t ¿¿¿ AVERIGUA LA RAIZ CUADRADA ???\n\n" );
    printf("Usted desea averiguar la raiz del numero:");
    scanf("%f",&numero);
    printf("\nIngrese la tolerancia que admitira en el resultado:" );
    scanf("%f",&tol);
    rta=calculo_raiz(numero,tol);
    printf("\nLa raiz de %.2f es %.2f\n",numero,rta);

    return 0;
}

float calculo_raiz(float num,float tolerancia)
{
    float r=0;
    float ra=1;
    int inc=1;

    while(inc>=1)
    {
        r=(1.0/2.0)*(ra+(num/ra));    // ó r=0.5*(ra+(num/ra));

        if((r-ra)<tolerancia)
        {
            return r;
        }
        else
        {
            inc++;
            ra=r;
        }
    }
}
```